# Not able to compress large file more than 10 GB using DotNetZIP

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I am able to compress up to 1 GB of the folder but I have to compress more than 10 GB.

```
 string filePath  = C:\Work; // path of the source file 
 private void compressFile(string filePath)
 {
     using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
     {                    
        zip.AddDirectory(Path.Combine(filePath, "Demo"));
        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(filePath, "Demo.zip")))
        {
           File.Delete(Path.Combine(filePath, "Demo.zip"));
           zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;                
           zip.Save(Path.Combine(filePath, "Demo.zip"));                        
         }   

         zip.Save(Path.Combine(filePath, "Demo.zip"));               
       }      
    }
```

Comment: I got This Exception...    Unable to compressIonic.Zip.ZipException: Compressed or Uncompressed size, or offset exceeds the maximum value. Consider setting the UseZip64WhenSaving property on the ZipFile instance.
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.SetZip64Flags()
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.PostProcessOutput(Stream s)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry._WriteEntryData(Stream s)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.Write(Stream s)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save()

Comment: Zip files are I believe limited to a maximum of 4GB in size

Comment: @stuartd zip64 extends that to 16 billion gigabytes; the first thing to try, then, is *exactly what the exception message says*; however, I'd still be very worried about the amount of data to buffer in memory

Comment: @MarcGravell yeah, I should have mentioned zip64.

Comment: @stuartd I have 15 GB of a folder which is having only text files, after zipping it will become nearly 2GB.

Comment: It may _end up_ at that size, but the error message is clearly telling you that something along the way is exceeding the maximum.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901652/net-ionic-zip-module-killing-drive-space) is related

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming the issue here is out-of-memory due to the fact that everything is in memory until the `zip.Save` call.

Suggestion: don't use `DotNetZIP`. If you use `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` instead, you *start* by giving it an output stream (in the constructor). Make that a `FileStream` and you should be set, without it needing to buffer everything in memory first.

You would need to use `ZipArchiveMode.Create`